# camera_node not found in package uvc_camera?

Tags: ros, roslaunch, uvc-camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I'm using ubuntu 13.04 ros hydro and I'm trying to run the camera_node on my in uvc_camera package using a launch file containing :

But I get this error **ERROR: cannot launch node of type [uvc_camera/camera_node]: can't locate node [camera_node] in package [uvc_camera]**.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/147151/camera_node-not-found-in-package-uvc_camera?/) by [Leyonce](https://answers.ros.org/users/13066/leyonce/) on ROS Answers with karma: 97 on 2014-04-01

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The correct node is now **uvc_camera_node**.

---

Originally posted by [Leyonce](https://answers.ros.org/users/13066/leyonce/) with karma: 97 on 2014-04-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Leyonce](https://answers.ros.org/users/13066/leyonce/) on 2014-04-01**:
I'm now wondering on why It was changed and not specified on wiki.ros.org/uvc_camera‎